# Position objects inline

Tags: javascript, jquery

See below code. How can I have the dropdown menu next to the `#drm_X` button? Currently it's below the `#drm_X` button.

Example:
I want it to be:

**BTN | BTN | MENU**

Currently it's:

**BTN | BTN |**

**MENU**

```
<div id="InputsWrapper"></div>
<script id="fs" type="text/template">
  <select name="dm" class="tMenu">
     <option value="Arial ">Arial</option>
     <option value="Times Roman ">Times Roman</option>
     </select>
     </script>
<script>

 function studentRec(e) {
        num++;
        var inWrap = $('<div />', { class: 'name-wrapper', id: 'inWrap_'+num }),
            nameWrap = $('<div />', { class: 'name' }).appendTo(inWrap),
            floatWrap = $('<div />', { class: 'tfArea', id: 'floatWrap_'+num }),
            outWrap = $('<div />').appendTo(floatWrap),
            tlsWrap = $('<div />').appendTo(floatWrap)

        nameWrap.append(
            $('<button />', { class: 'scienceL', text: 'Scirnce', type: 'button', id: 'sci_'+num  }),
            $('<button />', { class: 'dramaC', text: 'Drama', type: 'button', id: 'drm_'+num })
        );

            inWrap.append($($('#fs').html()).change(function(){
                //do something $(this).val();
            }));
```

Comment: did your `function` not working or did you want to `style` the position of appended items?

Comment: @Kyojimaru: I want to position the appended items in one line. Also is it possible to give the drop-down menu an ID when appending? Example `id: 'dropDown_'+num` ?

Comment: can you provide your current `HTML` markup with your problem in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), it should be possible if your `HTML` is correct

Comment: You don't need js for this, you can simply fix the alignment using css... Why do you need a dynamic `id` by the way? it's better to use css classes in dynamic templates...